# Generate link to list view by view name as parameter?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view

I am trying to work around a validation error when trying to generate a URL to get to a view. I know I can get to the view these ways:

1. https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Lists/ListName/ViewName.aspx
2. https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Lists/ListName/AllItems.aspx?viewid=viewGUID

Is there any way to pass the name of the view as a parameter? So something like

- https://contoso.sharepoint.com/Lists/ListName/AllItems.aspx?viewname=ViewName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, generate link to list view by view name as parameter is not work in SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. The closest to fit your requirement would be to get the view url using the API:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListName')/views/getByTitle('ViewName')?$select=ServerRelativeUrl
```